# Git init do not actually init the repository

Tags: git

Background: I'm migrating from one mac to another. There is a folder with existing git repository on the new machine, files are ok but rep isn't initialized, as expected. So:

```
Mac-mini-user:project user_wrk$ ls -lha | grep '.git'
drwxr-xr-x  17 user_wrk  staff   578B Apr 27 15:08 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 user_wrk  staff   249B Mar 11 15:21 .gitignore

Mac-mini-user:project user_wrk$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Users/user_wrk)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Mac-mini-user:project user_wrk$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/user_wrk/RubymineProjects/project/.git/
Mac-mini-user:project user_wrk$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Users/user_wrk)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Mac-mini-user:project user_wrk$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/user_wrk/RubymineProjects/project/.git/
```

As you may see above, git init is not very effective. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have git repositories in sub folders of the current directory?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Nope, just a regular rails application

Comment: I suppose your files under .git weren't copied correctly and completely. Try to recopy that. To check that try to remove .git totally, and launch `git init` once.